# Responsive Design JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am about to get into a project and I want it to be responsive. I have settled on using JavaFX. I know it uses CSS and FXML. I have looked everywhere for an implementation on responsive designs. Do I really have to create an implementation where I query the root layout for any size changes via a listener, and then change every node based on a percentage I set?

How do you guys handle this problem?

Comment: I think its based on which components you are planing to use for your project. Most of the provided UI-Controls and Panes usually responds automatically to changes made by user. If some components are within other components then you have to add the size propertys to the other child components.

Comment: When I use the .setMinWidth property on a VBox that's inside of a BorderPane, which is the root for the scene, I can resize it until I can no longer see anything. Shouldn't the VBox stop at the minWidth I set?

Comment: Use a [`GridPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html). The [`ColumnConstraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html) and [`RowConstraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/RowConstraints.html) can have their width and height, respectively, set as percentages.

Comment: When you use a `BorderPane` as parent node and a `VBox` as its child node, then it will always resizes to the width/height of the BorderPane.

Comment: Maybe you should set the `minSize` of the `BorderPane` instead of the `VBox`

Comment: There's also a good [presentation](https://www.parleys.com/talk/interface-layout-javafx-2-0) from Amy Fowler on JavaFX layout. It needs (free) registration and is a little old, but will still give you a decent overview of how everything works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reported issue: [Support media types in CSS to allow single CSS file to contain styles for desktop, tv and mobile](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091994)

AFAIK, currently you would have to provide a custom FXML/ CSS for each supported device.